# Does `substr` uses the same underlying memory?

Tags: c++, libstdc++

I heard that `std::string` uses an underlying reference counter to avoid copying the `std::string` data.

Does the `substr` method uses this or does it create a copy of the original `std::string`?

Since it is very implementation specific, lets focus on GNU's implementation initially.

Comment: Another question is - if it does, what happens when you modify either of the strings?

Comment: Look at the return value, it has to be copied

Comment: In C++98/03, reference counted implementations were allowed. As of C++11, it's no longer allowed (but some extant libraries still do it anyway, including the one most GNU distributions use by default). Still not sure it would do a substring as a reference to the same underlying data though.

Comment: [This example](http://ideone.com/ZoXX7k) suggests otherwise, nomatter whether I change abc at end or not.

Comment: @Kelm, the string implementation that uses reference counter does copy on modification if the value is shared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From cplusplus.com, [`string::substr()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)'s reference (emphasis added):

> Generate substring
>
> Returns a **newly constructed string object** with its value initialized to a copy of a substring of this object.
>
> The substring is the portion of the object that starts at character position `pos` and spans `len` characters (or until the end of the string, whichever comes first).

A peek into GNU's implementation shows it does construct a new string, using the [substring constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/basic_string/):

```
basic_string (const basic_string& str, size_type pos, size_type len = npos,
          const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
// or string (const string& str, size_t pos, size_t len = npos);
```

> substring constructor
>
> **Copies** the portion of `str` that begins at the character position `pos` and spans `len` characters (or until the end of `str`, if either `str` is too short or if `len` is `basic_string::npos`).

---

Testing GNU's implementation further, apparently the copy constructor does indeed use reference counting, while the substring constructor does not.